# Biztalk 2010 ESB itinerary custom Resolver and entity framwork connection

Tags: biztalk, esb

I have created a custom resolver and get data from database using Data access layer using entity framework 4.0, the entity framework connection string kept in BTSNtsvc.exe.config file

```
<add name="MadagascarDbEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*MadDb.csdl|res://*/MadDb.ssdl|res://*/MadDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
    connection string=&quot;data source=ttttt;initial catalog=MadagascarDb;persist security info=True;user id=eeeee;password=xxxxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

However I'm getting following error ...

```
The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly. 
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Resolver.ResolverMgr 
Method: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Resolver.ResolverInfo, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage, Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext) 
Error Source: mscorlib 
Error TargetSite: System.IO.Stream GetManifestResourceStream(System.String) 
Error StackTrace: at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetManifestResourceStream(String name)
```

any clues?

thanks for any help